# The best regex to parse Twitter #hashtags and @users

Tags: regex, cocoa-touch, twitter, utf-8, regexkitlite

Here is what I quickly came up with. It works with `regexKitLite` on the iPhone:

```
#define kUserRegex @"((?:@){1}[0-9a-zA-Z_]{1,15})";
```

Twitter only allows letters/numbers, underscores `_`, and a max of 15 chars (without `@`). My regex seems fine but reports false positives on e-mail addresses.

```
#define kHashtagRegex @"((?:#){1}[0-9a-zA-Z_àáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðòóôõöùúûüýÿ]{1,140})";
```

`kHashtagRegex` works with accentuated words but it is not enough for UTF-8 words.
What is the 'tech spec' of a hashtag?

Is there a reference somewhere on what to use for parsing these? Or do you have advice on how to enhance this regex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***I'm not sure if this is complete, bu this is what I would do:***

---

For the username, Add a check for whitespace/start of string before the `@` to eliminate emails `(?:^|\s)`:

```
#define kUserRegex @"((?:^|\s)(?:@){1}[0-9a-zA-Z_]{1,15})";
```

for the hash tags, I would just say \w or \d

```
#define kHashtagRegex @"((?:#){1}[\w\d]{1,140})";
```

Comment: This works for me as the hashtags could be made of any UTF-8 characters, so \w\d is fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
REGEX_HASHTAG = '/(^|[^0-9A-Z&\/\?]+)([#＃]+)([0-9A-Z_]*[A-Z_]+[a-z0-9_üÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ]*)/iu';`
```

Comment: Thanks man, but could you quote your sources / explain if it's yours.